# Porque no puedo insertar datos en esta tabla de SqlExpress 2014

Tags: sql-server

Buenos dias amigos estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla de sqlexpress 2014 valores, sin embargo me aparece este mensaje quien me pude ayudar 
estoy realizando esta tabla

```
create table EMP 
(
EMPNO int primary key not null,
ENAME varchar(50) not null,
JOB varchar (20) not null default 'Salesman',
MGR int,
HIREDATE date default '1-12-1980',
SAL decimal(5,2) not null,
COMM decimal(5,2) not null,
DEPTNO int  not null,
)
```

y trato de insertar los valores de esta manera

```
insert into EMP(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values 
(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,17/12/1980,800.00,null,20)
```

y me sale este mensaje

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 50 Conflicto de tipos de operandos:
>   int es incompatible con date

Comment: las fechas deben ir entre comillas, por que de lo contrario lo esta leyendo como número cuando en realidad debe ser formato de fecha

Comment: Tampoco está de más formatear las fechas en en un formato no ambiguo, es decir yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 0):

Deberia de ser algo asi:

```
insert into EMP(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) 
values 
(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,'17/12/1980',800.00,null,20)
```